# Renamed my project in XCode 6, can't build my project now

Tags: swift, xcode6

EDIT: I ended up creating a new project as suggested by justColbs and moving all of my classes plus the launchscreen.xib file and storyboard file into the new project directly in XCode and it works now! Yay for bugs, and I'm never going to try to rename a project again...

I renamed my project by selecting the .proj file, going to view, utilities, show file inspector. I changed the name in the upper right corner and then a window came up and I couldn't click the rename button, so I clicked don't rename and the play button greyed out.

All that shows up in my Devices list now is Mac OS.

I tried changing the name back, and it is now saying that I don't have a launch screen image for iPhone 4 retina displays, which wasn't an issue before this change.

How can I make it so I can build my project again?